# Apple calendar does not sync notifications on Google calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I have a Google Calendar which is synced with my MacBook Pro.

The events are syncing well, but the notifications do not: if I add a notification from my Mac, say at the beginning of the event, this will not appear in Google Calendar.

On the reverse direction it works thought (if I add a notification from Google calendar, or my Android smartphone, it will appear on my Mac).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you add the google mail account to your Mac's Internet Accounts? Or did you add your google calendar to your iCloud calendar? Both can be done, but which did you choose?

Comment: Hi Dennis. I could not find a solution to this issue. So eventually I bought an iPhone, that solved the problem (the alarms sync in both directions).

Comment: @MelvinJefferson the google account is added in the Mac's internet accounts. Mail etc. works just fine. Syncing events works just fine. Only the notifications are never synced to google for some reason.

Comment: @Arkandias two years later the issue is still present. Clap clap clap Apple.

Comment: For me, notifications imported works on Mac, not in iPhone iOS 16